# CSS Selector for hidding a text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Consider below HTML

```
<nav id="nav-main">
    <li> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png">
         <span>Sample Link</span>
       </a>
       Hide Me with CSS
   </li>
</nav>
```

Is it possible to remove or hide the **Hide Me With CSS** with CSS?

I tried:

```css
#nav-main li a:after{
    content: "";
}
```

But no luck.

http://jsfiddle.net/6powxzru/

I can not change the above HTML as this is a dynamically generated code (with a JSP tag).

Comment: First, your HTML is invalid, `<li>` elements are only valid under an`<ul>`, or `<ol>`, parent element.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/v5Lna9r5/ . You can use `:last-child`

Comment: @DavidThomas I think you mean `<ol>` not `<lol>`. `<lol>`

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6powxzru/3/) what you need?

Comment: @DavidThomas I know :( but I can not change it !

Comment: @Jacob: yes, I did. iPad autocorrect insists on autobreaking >.<

Comment: @KhanhTO no! you removed the Sample Link

Comment: @Harry yes, Please send it as answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to set `visibility: hidden` for the `li` and then set it to `visible` for the `a` inside the `li`.

```css
#nav-main li {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#nav-main li a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-main">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png">
      <span>Sample Link</span>
    </a>Hide Me with CSS</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: The one problem with this is the text still takes up space in the layout, it just isn't visible.

Comment: @JacobGray: Yes but that would depend on how the element is being put to use. If it is left as block by default and the text is small then it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

> I can not change the above html as this is a dynamically generated code

Change the `font-size`

```css
#nav-main li {
  font-size: 0;
}
#nav-main li a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-main">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" />
      <span>Sample Link</span>
    </a>
    Hide Me with CSS</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: I like it. Very nice :)

Comment: It is good, the only problem is that you should now the exact **font-size** to set it for **a**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the text node with JS:

```js
var node = document.querySelector('#nav-main > LI > A').nextSibling;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: Thanks and up voted, but I was asking for CSS selector !

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS has currently no means to select text nodes. Please note that using `visibility` does not prevent the hidden part of element from affecting layout.

Answer (score 1):

How about you try the following approach (not sure if possible in your case, though):

- Color **li** within **nav** with the background color of the whole container, so the text is not visible any more.
- After that, you would style individual elements based on colors you want. If the container background is white, you would start with:

  ## nav-main li{color:#FFF;}

  ## nav-main li a{color:#000;}

etc.

Answer (score 0):

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp):

> The ::after selector inserts something **after the content** of each selected element(s).

This means any content you add in the `after` "element" will appear after but still *inside* the original element, which in your case is the `a` tag.

Also, you cannot remove text using the `content` property which was not added using the `content` property. So, to hide such text which is outside the `a` but inside the `li` on a specific event, such as hover, you can instead do something like this.

```css
#nav-main li:after {
    content: "Hide Me With CSS";
}
#nav-main li:hover:after {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav-main">
    <li> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"> 
           <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png">
         <span>Sample Link</span>
       </a>
   </li>
</nav>
```